# Unknown errors in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am following the instructions for a tutorial but I cannot figure out what is wrong. I have double checked everything. I put the the compiler errors in the code's comments below. Sorry, this will probably show how much of a noob I am.

```
//  main.m


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LotteryEntry.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   // Creates the date object

    NSCalendarDate *now = [[NSCalendarDate alloc]init];

    //Seed the random number generator

    srandom(time(NULL));
    NSMutableArray * array;
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        //create a date/time object that is 'i' weeks from now

        NSCalendarDate *iWeeksFromNow;
        iWeeksFromNow = [now dateByAddingYears:0
                                         months:0
                                           days:(i * 7)
                                          hours:0
                                        minutes:0
                                         second:0];
    }

     //create the LotteryEntry object

     LotteryEntry *newEntry = [[LotteryEntry alloc]init];
     [newEntry prepareRandomNumbers];
     [newEntry setEntryDate: iWeeksFromNow]; 

//Error says "Use of undeclared identifier "iWeeksFromNow'. Did I not declare it above?

     //add the lottery entry object to the array

     [array addObject:newEntry];

     }

     for (LotteryEntry *entryToPrint in array) { 

//Error says " Expected identifier or '('


         //Display it's contents

         NSLog(@"%@", entryToPrint);

     }





[pool drain];
return 0;       
//Error says " Expected identifier or '('
}                  
//Error says " Expected External declaration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring iWeeksFromNow inside a for loop, that's why the compiler doesn't consider it to exist outside
declare it outside, and assign values to it inside

Comment: Yeah, Black Frog is right, the for loop is cut short, it should go to the     } under [array addObject:newEntry], instead of just after iWeeksFromNow

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra closing `}` as you call the -dateByAddingYears method.

Answer (score 1):

First error : you declare iWeeksFromNew inside a for loop, thus it's unreachable from outside.
You have to declare before the beginning of the loop.

Second error : you have a bracket '}' after `[array addObject:newEntry];` so the compiler thinks its the end of your method, remove it.

That should fix all other error you have

Answer (score 0):

First, `iWeeksFromNow` is declared within the scope of a `for` loop, so it will be visible only within that loop. Second, as pointed out by [Black Frog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571409/unknown-errors-in-xcode/5571439#5571439), you have an extra closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration out that loop block. You've got a scope problem here: The iWeeksFromNew only exists within the loop

```
NSCalendarDate *iWeeksFromNow;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    //create a date/time object that is 'i' weeks from now
    iWeeksFromNow = [now dateByAddingYears:0
                                     months:0
                                       days:(i * 7)
                                      hours:0
                                    minutes:0
                                     second:0];
}
```